# Vue SASS cannot load it globally

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass

Hi I'am trying to set sass globally on new VUE project. I tried so many times and still doesn't work.
Here is vue.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: ' @import \'@/sass/variables.sass\';',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Just base sass file

```
$base-color: #c6538c
```

and using of it in base App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="nav">
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
  </div>
  <router-view/>
</template>

<style lang="sass">

#nav
  padding: 30px

  a
    font-weight: bold
    color: $base-color

    &.router-link-exact-active
      color: #42b983

</style>
```

And Here is my package.json just for all version that I used.

```
{
  "name": "vertical-vue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^5.0.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "~3.9.3",
    "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-0"
  }
}
```

I will be very grateful for some suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding it in this format in your vue.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
 css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: '@import "~@/styles/variables.scss";' // Example path
      },
    },
  },
};
```

or better to downgrade your version to

```
"sass-loader": "7.3.1",
```

and the config will be using the data attr

```
module.exports = {
 css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: '@import "~@/styles/variables.scss";' // Example path
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: in module.exports={}??? Because if I changed with ur code I;ve got 4 missing trailing comma :/

Comment: did you change the path according to your structure?

Comment: I have added the commas...Please check my updated answer

Comment: Yes I've changed path exactly should be good but know I got an error Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'data'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }

Comment: I tried everything in 3 hours and still doesnt work eh

Comment: whats your sass loader version

Comment: Check my updated answer where I have replaced data with prependData. Let me know if that works

Comment: My sass loader version is 8.0.2 and it still doesnt work still the same Error module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: '@import "~@/sass/variables.sass";', // Example path
      },
    },
  },
};
Path is good i think src/sass/variables.sass

Comment: check my answer now where I have specified about downgrading

Comment: I downgraded sass loader to 7.3.1 still doesnt work, that dont see variable $base-color in App.vue but some erros shows its something in cji.js

Comment: then there might be another problem

Comment: the module build error has now disappeared right?

Comment: After I downgraded it to 7.3.1 and shutdown server then npm rebuild serve and it's working now

Comment: Yes, I hope that will work till I get my project done. Thanks for help!

Comment: Great, pls consider giving an upvote and accepting the answer if your problem is resolved